# InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain access token at OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I was trying to use `passport-google-oauth20` in my login page and got the following error.
I don't know what to do please help me to know what is this error.

```
InternalOAuthError: Failed to obtain access token
    at OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (C:\Users\guru3\OneDrive\Desktop\Secrets-StartinCode\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:423:17)
    at C:\Users\guru3\OneDrive\Desktop\Secrets-StartinCode\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:177:45
    at C:\Users\guru3\OneDrive\Desktop\Secrets-StartinCode\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:191:18
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\guru3\OneDrive\Desktop\Secrets-StartinCode\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:162:5)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:511:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:511:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

this is my code.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const GoogleStrategy= require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const findOrCreate = require('mongoose-findorcreate');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(session({

    secret: "this is our secret.",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: false }
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/userDB");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    email: String,
    password: String,
    googleId: String

});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){

    done(null, user.id);
  
  });
  
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){

    User.findById(id, function(err, user){

        done(err, user);

    });
});

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({

    clientID: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/google/secrets"

  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

    User.findOrCreate({ googleId: profile.id }, function (err, user) {

      return done(err, user);

    });
  }
));

app.get("/", (req,res) => {

    res.render(("home"))

})

app.get("/auth/google", 

    passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile"] })

)

app.get("/auth/google/secrets",

    passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/login" }),
    function(req, res) {

        res.redirect("/secrets");

    }

)

app.get("/login", (req,res) => {

    res.render(("login"))
    
})

app.get("/register", (req,res) => {

    res.render(("register"))
    
})

app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {

    req.logout(function(err) {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err); 
        }
    });

    res.redirect('/');

})

app.get("/secrets", function(req, res) {

    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        res.render("secrets")
    } else {
        res.redirect("/login")
    }

})

app.post("/register", (req,res) => {

    User.register({userName: req.body.username}, req.body.password, function(err, user) {

        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/register");
        } else {
            passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function() {
                res.redirect("/secrets");
            })
        }
    })
})

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    
    const user = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    })

    req.login(user, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, function() {
                res.redirect("/secrets");
            })
        }
    })
});

app.listen(3000, () => {

    console.log("Server started on port 3000...")

});
```